# Mongo DB - embedded array vs separate document

Tags: mongodb

My Question is related to Mongo DB - **embedded array vs separate document**.

I have following requirement.

An event can have multiple instances of dates(Start Date- End Date), in which for each instance the event details are same except events start date and end date.

User can add  many instances per event.

So in Mongo DB which of the following Structure would be suitable.

1. Having separate record/document for each instance.
2. Maintain array of instances in event document only.

Thanks in Advance.

Amol

Answer (score 0):

Well I would've gone for second option i-e

**Maintain array of instances in event document only.**

Because of the following

1. This would allow me manage the data in more efficient way like if I want to update name of the event for example, I won't have to update in all the rows if I had used the first option. In second case I just need to update a single row.
2. If I had to delete an event, again I'll have to deal with only one document in second case and in first case, I had to delete all those rows with that event
3. Don't know how I would have managed to mark different documents as the same event in the first case, instead, In second case I'd always have one unique Id for a particular event.
4. If I need I can `unwind` the document to number of documents, to use `aggregation` for example.